# Gearman-manager: Speed decreases when putty closed

Tags: gearman

SOLUTION:
**The solution that I found: using low level *nohup* program that ignores signal sent by putty when closing the connection. 
So, instead of** ./gearman-manager start **I did** nohup ./gearman-manager start

NOTE: **Still, I would like to know why was it slowing down when closing putty OR why does it continues in the first place if it has received the hangup signal???**

---

I have a problem with execution of a gearman worker after I close a putty session.
This is what I have:

- gearman client that is started with a cron job checking something in DB (infinite loop).
- gearman manager started with **gearman-manager start** command receiving client's tasks and managing the calls to a worker
- gearman worker reading/writing from DB and echoing the status of a current job

When I start gearman-manager I can see the echos from my worker when it receives task and when it executes them. Tasks (updates in DB) are executed cca. 1/second...

A) When I close putty session the speed of changes in DB decreases enormously (cca. 1/10sec)?! Could you tell me why is this?

B) When I log back with putty I don't get the outputs of gearman-manager back to the screen? I expected I'll log back into and see that it continues to echo the status like it did before closing putty? Maybe this could be because gearman-manager is started with owner **root** while the echoes are coming from .php ran as user **gearman**? or maybe when I log back into it the process is in the background?!

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the output when you create a new tty because the process was bound to the previous tty. Unless you use something like screen to keep the tty alive, you aren't going to see that output with a new terminal.